# Application.CurrentProject.CloseConnection fails after exporting from adp to accdb

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

So I have an *.adp file that connects to sql database and calls for stored procedures, changes/retrieves data etc. It stopped working after ms office 2013 installation.
I've exported all my code (forms, modules, macros) from *.adp file to the newly created empty *.accdb and it stopped working. I'm getting "method 'CloseConnection' of object CurrentProject failed" error.

```
Application.CurrentProject.CloseConnection

strConnect = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1" & ";Data Source=" & strServerName & _
  ";Initial Catalog=" & strDBName
If strUN <> "" Then
    strConnect = strConnect & ";user id=" & strUN
    If strPW <> "" Then
        strConnect = strConnect & ";password=" & strPW
    End If
Else 'Try to use integrated security if no username is supplied.
    strConnect = strConnect & ";integrated security=SSPI"
End If
Application.CurrentProject.OpenConnection strConnect

ChangeADPConnection = True
```

If i comment the line, I get another error for "Application.CurrentProject.OpenConnection" which says "Application.CurrentProject.OpenConnection refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exist". All these lines of code work nicely in .adp.
I assume there's some problem with the references, I copied them from the old file, but I'm guessing I need to use others for the new access file, the references are:

```
OLE Automation
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.1 Library
Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)
Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library
Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Microsoft Internet transfer control 6.0 (SP6)
Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3
```

Comment: From an older post I was involved with last year, the poster stated 'ADP's are no longer supported in 2013'. Our organization used an approach of defining the connection via ADO. Take a look at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27703248/how-to-set-application-currentproject-connection-in-accdb-project

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Wayne G. Dunn and my own research into the matter I've got my code working.
First of all these things don't work in new Access:

```
Application.CurrentProject.OpenConnection
Application.CurrentProject.CloseConnection
```

I had to make a new global variable for the connection:

```
Global dbConn As ADODB.Connection
```

and then use it in my methods. Function opening connection now looks like this:

```
Function ChangeADPConnection(strServerName As String, strDBName As _
   String, Optional strUN As String, Optional strPW As String) As Boolean
Dim strConnect As String
On Error GoTo EH:

If Not dbConn Is Nothing Then
  If (dbConn.State And adStateOpen) = adStateOpen Then dbConn.Close
  Set dbConn = Nothing
End If

Set dbConn = New ADODB.Connection


strConnect = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1" & ";Data Source=" & strServerName & _
  ";Initial Catalog=" & strDBName
If strUN <> "" Then
    strConnect = strConnect & ";user id=" & strUN
    If strPW <> "" Then
        strConnect = strConnect & ";password=" & strPW
    End If
Else 'Try to use integrated security if no username is supplied.
    strConnect = strConnect & ";integrated security=SSPI"
End If

dbConn.Open (strConnect)
ChangeADPConnection = True
dbConn.CursorLocation = adUseClient

Exit Function
EH:
 MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Connection"
 ChangeADPConnection = False
End Function
```

I also added an invisible form which fires an action on close that closes the connection. "dbConn.CursorLocation = adUseClient" is somehow also needed for filling the recordsets.